# Make/Install InkScape WinXP/MingW Link Crash

Tags: windows, mingw, inkscape

I am trying make/install inkscape on WinXp.  Although I am rather inexperienced on this subject, I have a reasonably well developed MingW infrastructure, and have successfully built/installed a variety of packages, such as Cairo, Pango, GTK+, Glade, etc.

At the moment I am trying to make/install inkscape.  Following a huge amount of work, it all configures and compiles, with  MSys:

```
cd ${LOCALBUILDDIR} && \
cd inkscape-0.91 && \
./configure --prefix=${LOCALDESTDIR} CFLAGS='-std=gnu++11' CXXFLAGS='-std=gnu++11' && \
make CFLAGS='-std=gnu++11' CXXFLAGS='-std=gnu++11' && \
make install
```

and after successful config/compile I use

```
cd ${LOCALBUILDDIR} && \
cd inkscape-0.91 && \
make CFLAGS='-std=gnu++11' CXXFLAGS='-std=gnu++11' && \
make install
```

to prevent recreating/overwriting the config etc files for the edits discussed below.

This fails on the link with:

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/build32/inkscape-0.91/src'
  CXXLD    inkscape.exe
libtool: link: cannot find the library `/usr/lib/libintl.la' or unhandled argument `/usr/lib/libintl.la'
```

At no time ever have I had any Dir's called "/usr".  I appreciate that is the default on Unix etc, but my installation has its libs in D:/Apps/MingW/local32/lib", and which certainly includes libintl.la (and all the required gettext and libintl bits, as it would need for the success with all the other packages).  Indeed, the inkscape configure and compile steps report finding libintl etc. correctly.  Also, it obtains the path correctly for the compiler, etc. as it would need to for the success with the compiler.

I am guessing that somewhere in the inkscape configure/in/ac/m4 etc bits, it has hard-wired, or something, the link step for libintl for Unix default.  I have tried many permutations to manually alter "/usr/lib" lines in the config and libtool files, but obtain the same link crash.

I would be grateful for any hints as to where to look for/correct this in inkscape (or even generally).

Comment: What is your definition for `$LOCALDESTDIR`?

Comment: MSys returns $LOCALDESTDIR sh: /local32: is a directory.  Which is the "/local32" portion of "D:/Apps/MingW/local32/lib".  That is the "core" dir for all of my MingW(32) installs/apps etc, and is set in a .bat file that is loaded when MSys is launched.

Answer (score 0):

OK, sussed it.  It wasn't libintl per se, even though that is the "error/crash message".

The problem was in libpopt.la, which had hardwired "/usr/lib" dependency, rather than correctly creating the .la for the Windows/MingW environment.

popt was required for inkscape.

I kept running AgenRansack on the inkscape build dir's looking for "/usr" etc, when I should have run AgentRansack on my /local32/lib dir.

It now compiles and links without complaint ... but doesn't launch ... oh well, on to that later :-(